# PHP Can't find file or wrong code

Tags: php

I have this code

```
     <?php
                                        error_reporting(E_ALL);
$date = date("F");
$count_my_page = ("../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviews" + $date + ".txt");
$hits = file($count_my_page);
$hits[0] ++;
$fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work, the error_reporting gives NO output and i have no idea what's  the problem with it... Help?

Comment: Change the `+`'s to `.` The `+` are JS concatenates, as opposed to PHP's equivalent being dots. Plus, if `$date` isn't part of the folder name "totalviews", change `../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviews` to `../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviews/` - Only you know what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Please post this as answer i will make it a +

Comment: You shouldn't modify your question with additional code. People who visit the question and accepted answer will ask questions. Please modify it to what it was http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27234713/1, and post it as a new question.

Comment: I performed a rollback. Please post it as [**a new question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nota: In response to your [**originally posted question/code**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27234713/1) without the added JS codes afterwards.

The [**added JS code**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27234713/2) should be posted as [**a new question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I have done a rollback to the originally posted question/code.

---

As per OP's request, comment to answer:

Change the `+`'s to `.` The `+` are JS concatenates, as opposed to PHP's equivalent being dots.

Plus, if `$date` isn't part of the folder name "totalviews",
change `../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviews`
to `../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviews/`

Comment: Can you help me with my second problem

Comment: @martijnmelchers I noticed your deleted answer with the codes. I suggest you post it as a new question, because JS is not something I'm good at. Which looks to me like JSON.

Comment: That makes two of us. This is the right answer and solved the question-asker's problem.

Comment: @JohnConde I won't have any hair left on my head if I keep scratching it like that lol - Oh well, what can you do. Problem's been solved and that is what's important.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yep, seems I was of victim of it too.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the + with . and $hits[0] shouldn't be in double quotes. Also as methioned above, the path to the file may be wrong.

```
$count_my_page = "../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviews" . $date . ".txt";
$hits = file($count_my_page);
$hits[0]++;
$fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
fputs($fp , $hits[0]);
fclose($fp);
```

You could simplify this to:

```
$count_my_page = "../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviews" . $date . ".txt";
file_put_contents($count_my_page, file_get_contents($count_my_page)+1);
```