# Javascript read from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I got this code

```
    var area = new Morris.Area({
    element: 'revenue-chart',
    resize: true,
    data: [
        {y: '2011 Q1', item1: 2666, item2: 2666},
        {y: '2011 Q2', item1: 2778, item2: 2294},
        {y: '2011 Q3', item1: 4912, item2: 1969},
        {y: '2011 Q4', item1: 3767, item2: 3597},
        {y: '2012 Q1', item1: 6810, item2: 1914},
        {y: '2012 Q2', item1: 5670, item2: 4293},
        {y: '2012 Q3', item1: 4820, item2: 3795},
        {y: '2012 Q4', item1: 15073, item2: 5967},
        {y: '2013 Q1', item1: 10687, item2: 4460},
        {y: '2013 Q2', item1: 8432, item2: 5713}
    ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['item1', 'item2'],
    labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
    lineColors: ['#a0d0e0', '#3c8dbc'],
    hideHover: 'auto'
});
```

But i want it to be like this (I made a question for the date now i want to make a chart of the hits Link to question: [PHP Can't find file or wrong code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234713/php-cant-find-file-or-wrong-code))

```
    var area = new Morris.Area({
    element: 'revenue-chart',
    resize: true,
    data: [
        {y: '2011 Q1', item1: <?php echo file_get_contents("../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviewsJanuari.txt ?>, item2: 2666},
        {y: '2011 Q2', item1: Same Code but for febuari, item2: 2294},
        {y: '2011 Q3', item1: March, item2: 1969},
        {y: '2011 Q4', item1: April, item2: 3597},
        {y: '2012 Q1', item1: May, item2: 1914},
        {y: '2012 Q2', item1: June, item2: 4293},
        {y: '2012 Q3', item1: Jule, item2: 3795},
        {y: '2012 Q4', item1: August, item2: 5967},
        {y: '2013 Q1', item1: September, item2: 4460},
        {y: '2013 Q2', item1: November, item2: 5713}
        {y: '2013 Q2', item1: December, item2: 5713}
    ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['item1', 'item2'],
    labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
    lineColors: ['#a0d0e0', '#3c8dbc'],
    hideHover: 'auto'
});
```

But it does not work, how do i make the Javascript read the file and is there a way without PHP?

Comment: but what is the content of ../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviewsJanuari.txt  ?
look if exists and if it contains special characters..\n, etc.
another way can use ajax..

Comment: It might work if you added in the missing `")` in your line.  Also, is this file a `.php` file?

Comment: Thanks i made a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Close the statment below ith an end quote

```
"../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviewsJanuari.txt ?
```

showul look like this :

```
"../adminpanel/pagecounters/totalviewsJanuari.txt ?"
```